How can the electron radial probability density be zero when the probability density is non zero in s-orbitals?
How can $|\Psi|^2 4\pi r^2\text{d}r=0$ while $|\Psi|^2 \ne 0$ in s orbitals?
In any s orbital, at the nucleus $|\Psi|^2 \ne 0$ but $|\Psi|^2 4\pi r^2\text{d}r=0$.
To me this makes no sense, how can probability density be non-zero yet probability in a small volume around the nucleus be zero. Am I misinterpreting the meanings of these terms?

The question as posed is incorrect. It is only s orbital for which the square modulus of the wavefunction is non zero at the nucleus. Should the first part of the question read "In any s orbital"?

Oh sorry my bad

Forget atoms for a while, they are too complicated. Imagine a solid ivory ball with radius R. What is its "$|\Psi^2|$" (so to say)? A constant. Now what is the radial distribution of a random point inside the ball?

Guides for formatting of chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics / Detailed / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

BTW perhaps you meant "yet probability density in a small volume around the nucleus be zero"?

Yeah I'll edit that.

Regarding the difference between probability density and radial probability distribution, this has been answered here on the site.
Regarding how an integral can be zero when the density at a point is defined and non-zero: it is a math question but relates to a standard operation (volume integral generated by summing over radial shells) which chemists commonly encounter in QM.
The expression $4 \pi r^2 dr$ is the volume of a shell of thickness $dr$ concentric with the origin.
What is $r$ equal to at the origin (the nucleus)?

 $r=0$

Can you generate a shell with non-zero volume at the origin?

 no

It follows that integrating over a function with a finite density at the origin results in a zero contribution from that position to the volume integral. This is true of the contribution from any single point: it's vanishingly small, ie zero.

So basically, the probability of finding the electron in a shell of thickness dr at the origin is zero because the volume of the shell tends to zero?

Can't this be treated analogously to a metal sphere where probability density is analogous to mass density and probability is analogous to mass? If we treat it as such then we can say that, at the centre of the sphere mass density is non-zero because there is non-zero mass distribution around that point but mass is zero because the volume at the centre is zero.

Yes, this is entirely a mathematical consequence of the definition of $|\Psi|^2 4\pi r^2\text{d}r$ as the probability of finding the particle in a shell of thickness $dr$ at a radius r. That shell becomes (converges to) a point with zero volume at the origin, so the radial probability density is zero at the origin for any finite density. A finite volume (a sphere, for instance) centered at the origin would not have zero probability (unless the probability density within happens to be zero throughout).

The wavefunction itself has no real physical meaning, it is the expression $|\psi|^2$ that is interpreted as the probability of the electron being somewhere, but where? You do need to specify what the coordinates are and as you ask about radial values $r$ this indicates that spherical polar coordinates are used instead of Cartesian $x,y,z$.  This is done simply for mathematical convenience and instead of $x,y,z$ we use $r,\theta,\phi$ where $r$ is the radial distance and $\theta,\phi$ are angles. (You should look the details up in your textbook).
The expression $|\psi|^2$ should now read $|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2$ and this is a number that gives the probability of the electron being at one position which is exactly at $r,\theta,\phi$. (More generally we write $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)^*\psi(r,\theta,\phi)$ where * indicates the complex conjugate. You might also want to indicate the three quantum numbers $n,\,\ell,\,m_\ell$ as subscripts)
However, this probability at one position is not what we are really interested in, what is more interesting is to find the chance of being at any distance $r$ to $dr$ no matter what the angles are and to do this we have to integrate over these angles. The calculation to find the chance of being at $r\to r+dr$ for an S-orbital, which is spherical, is shown below. As S-orbitals hasve no dependence on $\theta$ or $\phi$ so $\psi$ depends only on $r$ and so $r$ can be taken out of the angular parts of the integral to give
$$ \begin{align}prob(r)dr&=\int_0^{2\pi}1d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\sin(\theta)\;d\theta \;\psi(r)^*\psi(r)\;r^2 dr\\&= 4\pi r^2\psi(r)^*\psi(r) dr\end{align}$$
where we use $r^2\sin(\theta)\;dr\;d\theta\; d\phi$ as the small volume element which is the equivalent of $dxdydz$ when using cartesian coordinates. You can now see where the $4\pi r^2dr$ comes from.
The equation gives the chance of the electron being at a distance in a spherical shell $r\to r+dr$ and not at an exact position. Because of the uncertainty principle we can only know the electron's position to a limited extent so we can never measure it to be at exactly $r=0$.

So basically, |Ψ|^2 is the probability of finding the electron in the infinitesimal volume around a point specified by r,θ,Φ while |Ψ|^2 4πr^2dr is the probability of finding the electron in the volume of a spherical shell of thickness dr and radius r which is centered at the nucleus.

No.  |Ψ|^2 is a probability density ,  |Ψ|^2 4πr^2dr is a probability. They have different units, they are different things. You get from the former to the latter by integrating over a volume.

Oh okay that's much more clear now, thanks.

not in an infinitesimal volume but exactly at that point $r,\theta,\phi$ and yes about the volume in a shell $r\to r+dr$

@Ian Bush, the wording probability and probability density seems to differ between authors, or not distinguished at all. It seems that if the probability is $pr(..)$ that a variable $X$ has the value $x$ is $p_x=pr(X=x)$ then the distribution function is $F(x)=pr(X\le x)$ and the density function $f(x)=dF(x)/dx$ and so we interpret the probability density function as a probability by writing $f(x)dx=pr(X:(x\to x+dx))$.

@porphyrin Yes. You integrate the PDF to get a probability. Exactly.

The hint answer can be formulated as a counter-question "What is the probability of the electron occurrence at a single point?"
It is mathematically less than any given positive number, $\text{d}P=|\Psi|^2\text{d}V$.
Scientifically, it is zero for any given point, including the origin of the coordinate system as the only point with $r=0$.
